# My balanced panel data shows as unbalanced panel data. I cannot use "make.pbalanced()" and "is.pbalanced()" which have no effect

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, syntax-error, panel

I have a panel data set which has no missing values and all are numeric values only except the date which is in "month/day/year" format but in quarterly frequency.

There are no missing values at all. However, I still do not understand why my data is shown as unbalanced one when I run the "is.pbalanced()" code command.

I also cannot make it balanced by running "make.pbalanced()" code showing the errors I do not understand.

Even when I run "table(DATA$Firm, DATA$Date)" (screenshot attached below), the table output only shows 1 and 0. Thus, the id-time matches do not seem to duplicate more than these.

DATA is the data file I used (screenshot attached below as well) of this on the bottom as well. The data and output are too huge to attach full file here (only except the snapshot) so please understand.

I would appreciate if I can know how I can make this panel data usable despite of its obvious balanced characteristics I have. Thank you.

```
> DATA=pdata.frame(data,index=c("Firm","Date"))
> DATA<-make.pbalanced(DATA)
Error in seq.default(from = min_value, to = max_value, by = 1) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In make.pconsecutive.indexes(x, balanced = balanced, ...) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(df_index[, "times"]) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(df_index[, "times"]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

> is.pbalanced(DATA)
[1] FALSE
```

[image]

[image]

If I provide dput(DATA) for the first 20 rows in DATA, the output is as follows:

```
> dput(DATA)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(3L, 18L, 35L, 52L, 54L, 27L, 
28L, 44L, 45L, 60L, 61L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 28L, 30L, 45L, 47L, 
63L), .Label = c("12/31/1998", "12/31/1999", "12/31/2000", "12/31/2002", 
"12/31/2003", "12/31/2004", "12/31/2005", "12/31/2008", "12/31/2009", 
"12/31/2010", "12/31/2011", "12/31/2013", "12/31/2014", "12/31/2015", 
"12/31/2016", "12/31/2019", "12/31/2020", "3/31/1998", "3/31/1999", 
"3/31/2000", "3/31/2001", "3/31/2004", "3/31/2005", "3/31/2006", 
"3/31/2007", "3/31/2009", "3/31/2010", "3/31/2011", "3/31/2012", 
"3/31/2015", "3/31/2016", "3/31/2017", "3/31/2018", "3/31/2021", 
"6/30/1998", "6/30/1999", "6/30/2000", "6/30/2001", "6/30/2004", 
"6/30/2005", "6/30/2006", "6/30/2007", "6/30/2009", "6/30/2010", 
"6/30/2011", "6/30/2012", "6/30/2015", "6/30/2016", "6/30/2017", 
"6/30/2018", "6/30/2021", "9/30/1998", "9/30/1999", "9/30/2000", 
"9/30/2003", "9/30/2004", "9/30/2005", "9/30/2006", "9/30/2009", 
"9/30/2010", "9/30/2011", "9/30/2012", "9/30/2014", "9/30/2015", 
"9/30/2016", "9/30/2017", "9/30/2020"), class = "factor"), Firm =     structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("296", "10718", "52239", "100263", "100432", 
"101273", "102798", "102931", "103660", "105309", "105334", "106599", 
"106801", "107495", "107501", "107559", "107574", "107737", "107755", 
"107766", "107791", "108048", "108297", "108299", "108679", "108729", 
"108731", "110803", "111464", "111469", "111483", "111484", "111487", 
"111489", "111492", "111493", "111503", "111506", "111509", "111514", 
"111522", "111536", "111555", "111589", "111590", "111600", "111695", 
"111703", "111716", "111727", "111750", "111751", "111752", "111775", 
"111796", "111808", "111938", "111940", "111941", "111942", "111955", 
"111956", "112001", "112028", "112066", "112137", "112153", "112347", 
"112367", "112371", "112427", "112472", "112666", "112738", "112852", 
"113501", "113582", "113848", "113959", "114957", "114958", "116126", 
"116324", "117005", "135894", "135939", "146262", "154189", "1000001", 
"1000132", "1000181", "1000198", "1000234", "1000242", "1000517", 
"1000757", "1000858", "1000881", "1000897", "1001061", "1001172", 
"1001283", "1001526", "1001577", "1001616", "1001915", "1002018", 
"1002061", "1002312", "1002320", "1002374", "1002376", "1002587", 
"1002650", "1002815", "1002827", "1002835", "1002839", "1002923", 
"1003021", "1003053", "1003057", "1003059", "1003229", "1003260", 
"1003405", "1003495", "1003683", "1003698", "1003943", "1004349", 
"1004369", "1004594", "1004595", "1004628", "1004823", "1005002", 
"1005330", "1005419", "1005420", "1005519", "1005570", "1005575", 
"1005625", "1005629", "1006105", "1006110", "1006155", "1006217", 
"1006232", "1006379", "1006460", "1006474", "1006511", "1006676", 
"1006720", "1006781", "1006799", "1007050", "1007451", "1007518", 
"1007544", "1007561", "1007564", "1007606", "1007631", "1007708", 
"1007780", "1007831", "1007879", "1007890", "1007923", "1008222", 
"1008290", "1008336", "1008494", "1008501", "1008521", "1008541", 
"1008974", "1009297", "1009608", "1009702", "1009707", "1010040", 
"1010079", "1010118", "1010171", "1010179", "1010218", "1010383", 
"1010384", "1010456", "1010469", "1010513", "1010515", "1010523", 
"1010559", "1010680", "1010697", "1010871", "1010884", "1010892", 
"1011249", "1011315", "1011369", "1011532", "1011549", "1011550", 
"1011601", "1011608", "1011628", "1011633", "1011636", "1011666", 
"1011793", "1011813", "1011965", "1012183", "1012304", "1012356", 
"1012472", "1012850", "1012854", "1021617", "1024280", "1028649", 
"1032627", "1032628", "1037429", "1047191", "1078689", "1079592", 
"1085370", "1094670", "1095030", "1095890", "1098870", "1103990", 
"1116650", "1130830", "1136430", "1150911", "1164070", "1165550", 
"1167911", "1169072", "1169451", "1169570", "1169574", "1177670", 
"1199506", "1200034", "1200141", "1200336", "1201617", "1203212", 
"1203998", "1204112", "1204249", "1205697", "1205991", "1206695", 
"1209238", "1209508", "1231250", "1236950", "1239130", "1254611", 
"1261831", "1278491", "1299590", "1308650", "1349851", "1364272", 
"1371810", "1373451", "1415470", "1461924", "1462905", "1468726", 
"1470067", "1471922", "1475575", "1492469", "1493548", "1494156", 
"1497186", "1502005", "1503676", "1510039"), class = "factor"), 
    Country = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), X1 = c(3.28071e+11, 
    2.47603e+11, 2.68036e+11, 2.8843e+11, 3.12936e+11, 1.63006e+11, 
    1.62064e+11, 1.62003e+11, 1.75994e+11, 1.66539e+11, 1.90875e+11, 
    8.48942e+11, 9.11332e+11, 9.38555e+11, 9.11507e+11, 8.80528e+11, 
9.15665e+11, 8.83188e+11, 8.59914e+11, 9.23223e+11), X2 = c(420.9, 
109.62, 115.46, 170.57, 256.84, 245.79, 28.1, 320.61, 37.39, 
51.84, 24.73, 28.56, 149.12, 176.7, 204.86, 241.27, 245.69, 
328.73, 270.17, 225.57), X3 = c(1.397e+09, 6.826e+09, 8.407e+09, 
6.218e+09, 1.96e+09, 4.39e+08, 3.011e+09, 4.27e+08, 2.918e+09, 
1.738e+09, 3.219e+09, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 1.7844e+10, 
2e+05, 1.7161e+10, 2e+05, 2e+05), X4 = c(41.6563, 21.4688, 
29.8125, 37.0938, 33.6875, 28.25, 30.88, 29.31, 24.69, 28.99, 
26.13, 168.84, 168.16, 127.56, 177.26, 170.63, 163.85, 131.27, 
167.44, 158.21), X5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X6 = c(0.931431568, 
0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 
0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 
0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 
0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568, 0.931431568), X7 = c(0.270710059, 
0.277063061, 0.291823581, 0.431113358, 0.165191665, 0.031089322, 
0.00946807, 0.040553104, 0.012598261, 0.006557103, 0.008332575, 
0.003612478, 0.050244788, 0.387559494, 0.250535044, 0.081293992, 
0.179216725, 0.110762938, 0.197073477, 0.275862491), X8 = c(0.000327816, 
0.002603413, 0.002742109, 0.004050941, 0.000200038, 0.000115447, 
1.27133e-05, 0.000150589, 1.69164e-05, 2.43491e-05, 1.11887e-05, 
1.34145e-05, 6.74667e-05, 0.00044596, 0.000278949, 0.000109158, 
0.000133225, 0.000148728, 0.0001465, 0.000307149), X9 = c(0.270893931, 
0.318213603, 0.391916461, 0.289869936, 0.38006593, 0.011946002, 
0.04790828, 0.01161946, 0.046428549, 0.047294196, 0.051217786, 
4.59817e-07, 4.59817e-07, 4.59817e-07, 4.59817e-07, 0.283917419, 
4.59817e-07, 0.273050148, 4.59817e-07, 4.59817e-07), X10 = c(0.0002414, 
0.003316004, 0.004084039, 0.003020644, 0.000338686, 8.42066e-06, 
5.44127e-05, 8.19048e-06, 5.27321e-05, 3.33374e-05, 5.81716e-05, 
4.80818e-09, 4.80818e-09, 4.80818e-09, 4.80818e-09, 0.000322465, 
4.80818e-09, 0.000310122, 4.80818e-09, 4.80818e-09), X11 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X13 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X14 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X15 = c(7L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 25L, 12L, 24L, 15L, 22L, 10L, 18L, 10L, 9L, 
9L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 8L), X16 = c(0.579324474, 0.67828913, 
0.797352123, 0.65619424, 0.643443626, 1.362389303, 1.076926757, 
1.158663556, 1.326649492, 1.070007097, 1.263384865, 0.976581992, 
1.299930534, 1.665132357, 1.202016572, 1.076926757, 1.111254141, 
1.326649492, 0.885775977, 1.319718044), X17 = c(13.07130455, 
8.316492188, 8.766790769, 9.539716667, 12.43554545, 8.205709375, 
11.61956875, 9.233861538, 11.37893538, 10.52281061, 11.20804697, 
11.50165758, 12.36111364, 13.1170197, 16.01679545, 11.61956875, 
16.46697656, 11.37893538, 16.98400462, 15.10651515)), row.names = c("296-    12/31/2000", 
"296-3/31/1998", "296-6/30/1998", "296-9/30/1998", "296-9/30/2000", 
"10718-3/31/2010", "10718-3/31/2011", "10718-6/30/2010", "10718-6/30/2011", 
"10718-9/30/2010", "10718-9/30/2011", "52239-12/31/2010", "52239-12/31/2011", 
52239-12/31/2013", "52239-12/31/2014", "52239-3/31/2011", "52239-3/31/2015", 
"52239-6/30/2011", "52239-6/30/2015", "52239-9/30/2014"), class =     c("pdata.frame", 
"data.frame"), index = structure(list(Firm = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("296", "10718", "52239"), class = "factor"), 
Date = structure(c(1L, 6L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 
16L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 18L), .Label = c("12/31/2000", 
"12/31/2010", "12/31/2011", "12/31/2013", "12/31/2014", "3/31/1998", 
"3/31/2010", "3/31/2011", "3/31/2015", "6/30/1998", "6/30/2010", 
"6/30/2011", "6/30/2015", "9/30/1998", "9/30/2000", "9/30/2010", 
"9/30/2011", "9/30/2014"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(220L, 
7L, 11L, 13L, 196L, 1713L, 2161L, 1816L, 2274L, 1930L, 2379L, 
2052L, 2504L, 2983L, 3278L, 2162L, 3413L, 2275L, 3554L, 3121L
), class = c("pindex", "data.frame")))
```

The first 20 lines (rows) of DATA are as below. This is after I put "pdata.frame" so the first column as been added automatically accordingly:

```
DATA=pdata.frame(data,index=c("Firm","Date"))

DATA[1:20,]
                       Date  Firm Country          X1     X2         X3           X4 X5        X6          X7           X8           X9          X10 X11 X12 X13     X14 X15       X16       X17
296-12/31/2000   12/31/2000   296      30 3.28071e+11 420.90 1.3970e+09      41.6563  0 0.9314316 0.270710059 0.0003278160 2.708939e-01 2.414000e-04   0   0       0   0   7 0.5793245 13.071305
296-3/31/1998     3/31/1998   296      30 2.47603e+11 109.62 6.8260e+09      21.4688  0 0.9314316 0.277063061 0.0026034130 3.182136e-01 3.316004e-03   0   0       0   0   4 0.6782891  8.316492
296-6/30/1998     6/30/1998   296      30 2.68036e+11 115.46 8.4070e+09      29.8125  0 0.9314316 0.291823581 0.0027421090 3.919165e-01 4.084039e-03   0   0       0   0   2 0.7973521  8.766791
296-9/30/1998     9/30/1998   296      30 2.88430e+11 170.57 6.2180e+09      37.0938  0 0.9314316 0.431113358 0.0040509410 2.898699e-01 3.020644e-03   1   0       0   0   2 0.6561942  9.539717
296-9/30/2000     9/30/2000   296      30 3.12936e+11 256.84 1.9600e+09      33.6875  0 0.9314316 0.165191665 0.0002000380 3.800659e-01 3.386860e-04   0   0       0   0   3 0.6434436 12.435545
10718-3/31/2010   3/31/2010 10718      30 1.63006e+11 245.79 4.3900e+08  28.2500      0 0.9314316 0.031089322 0.0001154470 1.194600e-02 8.420660e-06   0       0   0   1  25 1.3623893  8.205709
10718-3/31/2011   3/31/2011 10718      30 1.62064e+11  28.10 3.0110e+09      30.8800  0 0.9314316 0.009468070 0.0000127133 4.790828e-02 5.441270e-05   0   0       0   1  12 1.0769268 11.619569
10718-6/30/2010   6/30/2010 10718      30 1.62003e+11 320.61 4.2700e+08      29.3100  0 0.9314316 0.040553104 0.0001505890 1.161946e-02 8.190480e-06   0   0       0   1  24 1.1586636  9.233862
10718-6/30/2011   6/30/2011 10718      30 1.75994e+11  37.39 2.9180e+09      24.6900  0 0.9314316 0.012598261 0.0000169164 4.642855e-02 5.273210e-05   0   0       0   1  15 1.3266495 11.378935
10718-9/30/2010   9/30/2010 10718      30 1.66539e+11  51.84 1.7380e+09      28.9900  0 0.9314316 0.006557103 0.0000243491 4.729420e-02 3.333740e-05   0   0       0   1  22 1.0700071 10.522811
10718-9/30/2011   9/30/2011 10718      30 1.90875e+11  24.73 3.2190e+09      26.1300  0 0.9314316 0.008332575 0.0000111887 5.121779e-02 5.817160e-05   0   0       0   1  10 1.2633849 11.208047
52239-12/31/2010 12/31/2010 52239      30 8.48942e+11  28.56 2.0000e+05     168.8400  0 0.9314316 0.003612478 0.0000134145 4.598170e-07 4.808180e-09   0   0       0   1  18 0.9765820 11.501658
52239-12/31/2011 12/31/2011 52239      30 9.11332e+11 149.12 2.0000e+05     168.1600  0 0.9314316 0.050244788 0.0000674667 4.598170e-07 4.808180e-09   0   0       0   1  10 1.2999305 12.361114
52239-12/31/2013 12/31/2013 52239      30 9.38555e+11 176.70 2.0000e+05     127.5600  0 0.9314316 0.387559494 0.0004459600 4.598170e-07 4.808180e-09   0   0       0   0   9 1.6651324 13.117020
52239-12/31/2014 12/31/2014 52239      30 9.11507e+11 204.86 2.0000e+05     177.2600  0 0.9314316 0.250535044 0.0002789490 4.598170e-07 4.808180e-09   0   0       0   0   9 1.2020166 16.016795
52239-3/31/2011   3/31/2011 52239      30 8.80528e+11 241.27 1.7844e+10     170.6300  0 0.9314316 0.081293992 0.0001091580 2.839174e-01 3.224650e-04   0   0       0   1  12 1.0769268 11.619569
52239-3/31/2015   3/31/2015 52239      30 9.15665e+11 245.69 2.0000e+05     163.8500  0 0.9314316 0.179216725 0.0001332250 4.598170e-07 4.808180e-09   0   0       0   0  15 1.1112541 16.466977
52239-6/30/2011   6/30/2011 52239      30 8.83188e+11 328.73 1.7161e+10     131.2700  0 0.9314316 0.110762938 0.0001487280 2.730501e-01 3.101220e-04   0   0       0   1  15 1.3266495 11.378935
52239-6/30/2015   6/30/2015 52239      30 8.59914e+11 270.17 2.0000e+05     167.4400  0 0.9314316 0.197073477 0.0001465000 4.598170e-07 4.808180e-09   0   0       0   0  20 0.8857760 16.984005
52239-9/30/2014   9/30/2014 52239      30 9.23223e+11 225.57 2.0000e+05     158.2100  0 0.9314316 0.275862491 0.0003071490 4.598170e-07 4.808180e-09   0   0       0   0   8 1.3197180 15.106515
>
```

Comment: Could you provide `dput(data)` for a few firms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of `is.pbalanced`:

> Balanced data are data for which each individual has the same time periods

As an example:

```r
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
is.pbalanced(Grunfeld)
#> [1] TRUE
table(Grunfeld$firm,Grunfeld$year)
#>     
#>      1935 1936 1937 1938 1939 1940 1941 1942 1943 1944 1945 1946 1947 1948 1949
#>   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   2     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   3     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   4     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   5     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   6     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   7     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   8     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   9     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   10    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1


non.balanced <- Grunfeld[-sample(200,10),]
is.pbalanced(non.balanced)
#> [1] FALSE
table(non.balanced$firm,non.balanced$year)
   
#>      1935 1936 1937 1938 1939 1940 1941 1942 1943 1944 1945 1946 1947 1948 1949
#>   1     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   2     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   3     1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   4     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1
#>   5     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   6     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   7     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   8     1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
#>   9     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1
#>   10    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

As shown above, `table` of a pbalanced dataset doesn't have zeros : the periods are the same for every firm.

You can verify this in `pbalanced` [source code](https://rdrr.io/rforge/plm/src/R/is.pconsecutive_pbalanced.R):

```
is.pbalanced.default <- function(x, y, ...) {
  if (length(x) != length(y)) stop("The length of the two vectors differs\n")
  x <- x[drop = TRUE] # drop unused factor levels so that table 
  y <- y[drop = TRUE] # gives only needed combinations
  z <- table(x, y)
  if (any(v <- as.vector(z) == 0L)) {
    balanced <- FALSE # Any zero means False
  } else { balanced <- TRUE
```

`table` of the dataset you're using has many zeroes, which explains why `is.pbalanced(DATA)==FALSE`

[image]

It would be useful to provide `dput(data)` to find out why `make.pbalanced` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much. So the same time period means the above outcome matrix would be all same numbers which can be anything (e.g., 2, 3, 4, etc.) including ones you have shown, right?

Comment: the numbers **should all be 1**, meaning that there's one value per firm and per time period, see my edit

Comment: Thanks again. However, when I use "make.pbalanced(DATA)", I receive the following errors which I do not understand how to fix: Error in seq.default(from = min_value, to = max_value, by = 1) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In make.pconsecutive.indexes(x, balanced = balanced, ...) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(df_index[, "times"]) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(df_index[, "times"]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Could you supply a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with data causing the problem?

Comment: I have done so in my question above for the first 20 rows of DATA only due to post size limit. Please check. Also, the error message from make.pbalanced(DATA) remains the same as above. All I need is to know how to fix this in an easy manner.

Comment: Does the `dput` you provided work on your computer? I get an error. Note that I was able to create the error you get by putting an empty string in the Date column of the Grunfeld example `Grunfeld[1,2]<-""`. Could you check **if you have no empty strings** in `Date`? This results in `Inf` for max and `-Inf`for min because `max(numeric(0))` is Inf

Comment: Yes 'dput' works on my computer as you see above. I see no missing dates across my entire sample I have. The dates are provided in "month/date/year" format e.g., 6/30/2021.

Comment: Now I also added the first 20 rows of data used for this above. Please check this as well. As you can see, no empty strings.

Comment: could you try `make.pbalanced(data)` instead of `make.pbalanced(DATA)`

Comment: May I first know what you want to happen? The dput has already been applied on DATA before inputting into the make.pbalanced function.

Comment: `pdata.frame` transforms dates to non standard date format :`17-12/31/2013`, I suspect it to be the cause of the error, hence my question to run `make_pbalanced` on raw data instead of transformed DATA

Comment: I also suspect date format in .labels of Date factor to be a problem. You could try to reformat, for example : `format(as.Date("12/31/1998","%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: When I use the pure data over the make_pbalanced without transforming into pdata.frame, the R code running gets stuck. I am not sure whether this requires very long run time but I had to terminate and open it up again. If so, do you suggest transforming the dates again as in your latest comment?

Comment: Ok. I clearly see that if I use pdata.frame over my data, I get errors above. Otherwise, however, the run time is long which I am still waiting for it to complete executing. I am not sure whether this will work, but just for in case, is there an easy manual way to make the data pbalanced like in the excel sheet where the data are in?

Comment: To save my time, now I have tried using only 20 rows in front to run this code. Please note that my original data set has no missing values at all. Then, however, I get the following warning error when running make.pbalanced(DATA): Warning message:
In mde(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: I would be glad to help further, but when I try to run the dput you provided, it creates an error. Are you able to run the result of the dput (ie the `structure(...)`)  in your console?

Comment: Yes dput works both on my raw data and my pdata.frame transformed data.

Comment: If you see the data above, there is one cell which shows a slight shift of value (below X4 and X12) to the right simply due to the copy & paste issue on this website.

Comment: dput works, but when you copy/paste the result =  `structure(..)`, does it recreate the object in your workspace?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean = structure(..)? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231366/discussion-between-waldi-and-eric).